# Adding a DOM element by changing innerHtml of a div prevents it to be found later with getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div and I'm using javascript to add a new element inside it

**Original Div:**

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML ="<div id='bar'></div>";
```

**Result**

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

But after executing this code I try to retrieve the element (in order to focus on it) doing

```
 document.getElementById('bar')
```

But this returns an empty object.

So does adding an element using innerHtml not really add the element to the DOM? And what is the right way to add an element that could be retrieved later by `getElementById`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works perfectly - make sure you're running it in the correct order:

```js
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML ="<div id='bar'>Bar</div>";
console.log(document.getElementById("bar"));
```

```html
<div id="foo">Foo</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `createElement` and `appendChild`

```js
    var barDiv = document.createElement('div');
    barDiv.id = 'bar';
    document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(barDiv);
    document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = 'bar';
    
    console.log(document.getElementById('bar'));
```

```html
<div id="foo">Foo</div>
```